# Proof of $sin$ formula.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals, summation

I am reading  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17966/947379) quesiton and accepted answer.

Question is about proof.

$S = \sin{(a)} + \sin{(a+d)} + \cdots + \sin{(a+nd)}$

$S \times \sin\Bigl(\frac{d}{2}\Bigr) = \sin{(a)}\sin\Bigl(\frac{d}{2}\Bigr) + \sin{(a+d)}\cdot\sin\Bigl(\frac{d}{2}\Bigr) + \cdots + \sin{(a+nd)}\cdot\sin\Bigl(\frac{d}{2}\Bigr)
$

After cancellation I get $S * \sin(\frac{d}{2})=\frac{1}{2}(\cos(a-\frac{d}{2})-\cos(a+\frac{d(2n+1)}{2}))$

So I need to prove that $\frac{1}{2}(\cos(a-\frac{d}{2})-\cos(a+\frac{d(2n+1)}{2}))$ = ${\sin(n \times \frac{d}{2})} \times \sin\biggl( \frac{2  a + (n-1)\cdot d}{2}\biggr)$

This is where I don't know how to prove

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis#Reverse_identities) & [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis_Formulas/Cosine_minus_Cosine).

Comment: @J.G. Thank you!